# Can I create a new object based on its type?

Tags: vb6

Given an object of type clsPerson:

```
dim oP as New clsPerson
oP.FirstName = "Sam"
```

is there a way to interrogate variable `oP` and a create a new object of that type?

Comment: `TypeName(oP)` should give you the name of the class (in this case, `clsPerson`). Or are you trying to take the name of the class and use something like `CreateObject` to programmatically create it?

Comment: @Jp That is exactly what I am trying to do.  But CreateObject fails, so I abandoned that approach.  It seems that CreateObject works on objects that are registered in the registry.

Comment: I tried `CreateObject(TypeName(oP))` and it fails. It seems you have to already have some idea of the object's ProgID.

Comment: No, not for private classes within your project.  You could implement a Clone method to do this (or better yet, an IClonable interface).

Comment: @tcarvin: `IClonable` is supposed to duplicate internal state too. OP just needs a new empty instance.

Comment: @tcarvin I figured out how to do automatic Clone for private classes.  That works fine.  Like `wqw` said, I just need a new empty instance.

Comment: @AngryHacker If implementing an interface is not a problem, then also implement `IEmptyClonable`. Would be a bit silly in terms of proper OP as it should actually be a static method, but will work as a member method.

Comment: Well instead of Clone call it CreateInstance...the concept was what was important.

Comment: @GSerg What is `IEmptyClonable`?  Google returns nothing.

Comment: @AngryHacker It's an interface I just invented. It contains just one method that returns a blank object of the implementing type. I mean, there's no `IClonable` in VB6 either, it's just something you yourself define in your project and then make your classes `Implements` it.

Comment: @GSerg I see, I thought you were talking about an interface in the TypeLib Info dll.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class is properly registered with COM (that is, coming from an ActiveX dll project), then yes:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type Guid
  Data1 As Long
  Data2 As Integer
  Data3 As Integer
  Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type

Private Const CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER As Long = 1
Private Const IID_IUnknown As String = "{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

Private Declare Function CLSIDFromString Lib "ole32.dll" (ByVal lpsz As Long, ByRef pclsid As Guid) As Long
Private Declare Function IIDFromString Lib "ole32.dll" (ByVal lpsz As Long, ByRef lpiid As Guid) As Long
Private Declare Function CoCreateInstance Lib "ole32.dll" (ByRef rclsid As Guid, ByVal pUnkOuter As Long, ByVal dwClsContext As Long, ByRef riid As Guid, ByRef ppv As Object) As Long



Public Function GetAnotherInstanceOf(ByVal this As Object) As Object
  Static iunk As Guid
  If iunk.Data4(7) = 0 Then
    IIDFromString StrPtr(IID_IUnknown), iunk
  End If

  Dim ti As TLI.TypeInfo

  With New TLI.TLIApplication
    Set ti = .ClassInfoFromObject(this)
  End With

  Dim clsid As Guid
  CLSIDFromString StrPtr(ti.Guid), clsid

  CoCreateInstance clsid, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, iunk, GetAnotherInstanceOf
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim s As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

Dim clone As Object

MsgBox TypeName(clone)
Set clone = GetAnotherInstanceOf(s)
MsgBox TypeName(clone)
```

The `TLI` is `TypeLib Information` found in Project -> References.

Comment: `GetAnotherInstanceOf` doesn't actually return anything.

Comment: @AngryHacker It does. The return value buffer of the function is passed by reference to the API and gets filled with a pointer.

Comment: I see, pretty clever.  Here is the problem though.  The object is an internal object private to the EXE.  So `.ClassInfoFromObject` won't work.  But you are after the GUID, so I tried `.InterfaceInforFromObject`, which also returns a GUID.  However, the return value of GetAnotherInstanceOf is always Nothing.  Can this work for internal objects?

Comment: @AngryHacker No, that's GUID of the interface. You can't create an interface as any object can implement that interface.

Comment: ClassInfoFromObject() gives error 430 for me, but InterfaceInforFromObject() works fine. Anyway, from my previous experience with this library, referencing typelib only works on VB IDE and doesn't work with the compiled EXE, is this True, or you know any workaround for this? We're talking about c:\windows\system32\TLBINF32.DLL right?

Comment: @AngryHacker `ClassInfoFromObject` fails because there is no COM class info to retrieve (class not registered in the system). Other than that, works for me in exe as well.

Comment: @GSerg So what you are saying is that I can't create an instance of a private object, period?

Comment: @AngryHacker I'm tempted to say Yes, but I am not *that bloody sure*.

Comment: I just created an empty `Standard EXE` project and added a class. Then `Debug.Print TypeName(CreateObject("Project1.Class1"))` printed `Class1`.

Comment: @GSerg TIL that word OK has entered the Russian dictionary :)

Comment: @wqw Same. That could be a bug that has been fixed. Are you using VB6 SP6?

Comment: @GSerg: Yes, I am. I think it's an expected behavior of `CreateObject` to be able to instantiate private (to the project only) objects, otherwise we could just use `CoCreateInstance` directly.

Comment: @wqw Then you can post an answer. However, the [OP observes the same behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125094/can-i-create-a-new-object-based-on-its-type/11126005#comment14579386_11125094).